# In-App Currency Offers JSON issue

Tags: php, facebook, json

The callback from the Earn Chips Offerwall on Facebook does not seem to think the following string is valid JSON:

```
    {"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","credits":{"order_details":"{\"order_id\":306370426075228,\"buyer\":501702705,\"app\":124611564308567,\"receiver\":501702705,\"amount\":1,\"update_time\":1326747520,\"time_placed\":1326747519,\"data\":\"\",\"items\":[{\"item_id\":\"0\",\"title\":\"15000000 FullStack Poker Chips\",\"description\":\"Get FullStack Poker Chips\",\"image_url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/external.ak.fbcdn.net\\\/safe_image.php?d=AQBm3ERdBXy3wQO4&url=http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fwww.iplaypokerfb.com\\u00252Ffb_graph3\\u00252Fimages\\u00252Ffbc6.jpg\",\"product_url\":\"\",\"price\":1,\"data\":\"{\\\"modified\\\":{\\\"product\\\":\\\"http:\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\/apps.facebook.com\\\\\\\/fullstackpoker_dev\\\\\\\/earn_lander\\\\\\\/earn\\\",\\\"product_title\\\":\\\"FullStack Poker Chips\\\",\\\"product_amount\\\":15000000,\\\"credits_amount\\\":1}}\"}],\"status\":\"placed\"}","status":"placed","order_id":306370426075228,"test_mode":1},"expires":1326751200,"issued_at":1326747520,"oauth_token":"AAABxVWQGiFcBAJWhbUlHq8iRz7YuybEsUh9tUfjdSRbogcentYMEZA60ESLdyVLiX1TjPZBmXk03iFKTpkvr6l1d1IwdCbrpwo13BOCAZDZD","user":{"country":"us","locale":"en_US","age":{"min":21}},"user_id":"501702705"}
```

However, when I check it in an online parser or validator it says it is valid JSON.

I am using PHP 5.2.17. I have used JSON many times with no issue. Please let me know if anyone knows how to parse this in PHP as currently it comes out void using the Earn Chips Offerwall callback.

Answer (score 2):

That JSON is perfectly valid. See http://jsonlint.com/

So resorting to guesses in absence of context:

- There is a [`UTF-8 BOM`](http://www.google.com/search?q=UTF-8%20BOM) in front of the content.
- You receive different data with misencoded Unicode.
- See also the search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json_decode%20returns%20null

Otherwise try [`Services_JSON`](http://www.google.com/search?q=Services_JSON) or the variant from [`upgradephp`](http://www.google.com/search?q=upgradephp).

Answer (score 0):

```
"order_details":"{\"order_id\"
```

Is that an unnecessary double quote? I would this this fragment should be like:

```
"order_details": {"order_id": ...
```

Comment: No, the order_details array contains a string which is also json but it is not meant to be processed at the first run. Its json within json.

Comment: I would double check on that. Json array are contained within `[` and `]`. JSON is JSON even if it is within a JSON.

Comment: Well my question is simple... can you parse this string in php. It is valid JSON and parses well online in the parser or validator. You can try it yourself.

Comment: No, php isn't able to parse your json. try it yourself. In php you can use `json_decode` to decode json strings. If it returns `NULL` it could not decode the string.